# Error when creating collection in backbonejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to learn backbonejs and im having weird error that i don't seem to understand.
So basicaly i have a Channel with a ChannelsCollection when i try to create the ChannelsCollection on last line of code i get an error.

```
var Channel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: -1,
        name: 'No Name'
    }
});

var ChannelsCollection = new Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Channel
});

ch1 = new Channel({
    name: 'Channel 1',
    id: '1'
});

ch2 = new Channel({
    name: 'Channel 2',
    id: '2'
});

var channels = new ChannelsCollection([ch1, ch2]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8U9Lv/

Comment: copy paste error happen and it's kinda hard to see some things sometime when you wrote the code yourself and when the stuff is kinda new to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake:

var ChannelsCollection = `new` Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Channel
});

Remove the `new` here.

By the way, you do not need to pass Models to Collection.

We often pass a list of raw object to a collection.

So you could use it like this:

```
ch1 = {
    name: 'Channel 1',
    id: '1'
};
ch2 = {
    name: 'Channel 2',
    id: '2'
};

var channels = new ChannelsCollection([ch1, ch2]);

console.log(channels);
```

Because we have `model: Channel` here it the Colletion, Colletion knows how to handle it.

Comment: thx for pointing this out but i already knew that. The code used in ch1 and ch2 was copy paste from another example. But if i didn't use model:Channel in the collection i'd have to use "new Channel..."

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a "new" before Backbone.Collection.extend which caused an obvious stupid error.